# Why can't I break while command here?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I am writing an online shopping code in C, I don't know why but my code goes into an infinite loop and the `scanf` function in the block does not work. Even if I add `if (b <= a){break;}`. My friend tried to run it on Linux and got a different result. It just writes "insufficient margin please add" several times depending on the input. Here's my code;

```
int a;
int b = 100;
int add;
scanf("%d",&a);
while(a < b)
{
    printf("unsiffcent margin please add");
    scanf("add%d",&add);
    a = a + add;
}
```

I tried adding `if(b <= a){break;}` but doesn't work. I want a code that ask me to add to a number until number is greater than a value.

Comment: `scanf("add%d",&add);` expects input such as "add 42<ENTER>". Is that your intent?

Comment: What is with all the backslashes in posted code today? Did Stack Overflow change something in the UI?

Comment: I deleted add part and it works just fine. Thank you!

Comment: You should always check the return value from `scanf()` to make sure you got all the values you expected.  When the format is `"add%d"`, the user must type `add 123` (space optional).  If they type anything else, the code goes into an infinite loop with `scanf()` repeatedly returning 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are errors in your code:

- `while(a\<b)` will cause a syntax error. you probably meant `while (a <= b)`.
- `a` is not assigned a value in your code.

Here is what you want to do:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int max = 100, a = 0, add = 0;
    
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    
    while(a <= max) {
        printf("Unsufficient margin please add another number: ");
        scanf("%d", &add);
        a += add;
    }
    
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
}
```

You have to provide a prompt message so the user knows he is supposed to do something. And better, give your variables meaningful names.

---

Side note: [`scanf()` is not recommended to ask for user input](https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Answer (score 0):

```c
scanf("%d",&add);
```

will solve your problem.

Comment: No, it won't solve it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).